# Python ftplib log into ftp server with method "ftp.login(variable, variable)"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftp-client, ftplib

Im wanting to make a ftp client from scratch. so i want to (in the future) get the text that the user entered in the text field and store it as a variable. Later when the user clicks on "Connect", the program will take those variables and use them for the credentials in `ftp.login(user, pas)`

This is my code below:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import ftplib

user = 'admin'
pas = 'password'

try:
    ftp = FTP('allpcexperts.com')
    print 'using %s : %s'%(user,pas)
    ftp.login(user,pas)
    print "Success: %s:%s" %(user, pas)
except ftplib.error_perm as error:
    if error:
        print 'Login Failed'
```

this and along with all the other methods of printing strings give me this same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp.py", line 10, in <module>
    ftp.login(user,pas)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 392, in login
    resp = self.sendcmd('USER ' + user)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 222, in getresp
    raise error_temp, resp
ftplib.error_temp: 451 The parameter is incorrect.
```

Now, obviously i dont have much done, i want to get logging in "dynamically" working before creating the GUI part of the program.

I tried to use different methods of printing as taught from "Learn Python the Hard Way". `ftp.login(user, pas)`, `ftp.login('%s'%user, '%s'%pas)`, i even made separate variables to, recreate(?) the string. But so far the only method that works is to write the username and password statically into the `ftp.login()` method as such `ftp.login('admin','password')`.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I turned on debugging as suggested by Martin, and apparently the client was sending `admin\n` instead of just `admin` alone. So what i need to do is strip down the list item before using it in the `ftp.login()` method.

Debugging message:

```
*cmd* 'USER admin\n'
*resp* '451 The parameter is incorrect.'
```

Comment: Where do you set `user` and `pas`?

Comment: @Chris ah yea, i excluded those lines. sorry. ill update it

Comment: The error *"451 The parameter is incorrect"* comes from the server. Set `FTP.set_debuglevel` and show us the log + What FTP server is that? (I assume IIS) Do you have an access to the server-side log?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl If you could post your comment as an answer since it practically told me what was going on. Thanks!

Comment: @xR34P3Rx You better post your actual solution as an answer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl alright, when i fix it i will.

Answer (score 1):

Trying your code above, (more or less), I get:

```
In [1]: from ftplib import FTP

In [2]: import ftplib

In [3]:

In [3]: user = 'admin'

In [4]: pas = 'password'

In [5]: try:
   ...:     ftp = FTP('allpcexperts.com')
   ...:     ftp.login(user,pas)
   ...: except ftplib.error_perm as error:
   ...:     print error
   ...:
530 User cannot log in.
```

With the `530` being expected with that username and password.

As a result I suggest that you start from the code that posted above and substitute real valid username and password pair.

Comment: it does the same thing even with a valid account but i know my issue now. ill update the issue that i found